# Using a flap sand disc to remove the finish from a closet door

Tags: sanding

This is related to something that I am working on, described here:
[How should I refinish vintage wooden closet doors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48527/closet-doors-makeover/)

Is it possible to remove the existing finish with a flap sand disk like  the one below ?
[image]
I have tried my chance with a sander but no luck. I am afraid to test it with the belt sander.

Q: Is there a version of the below disk that can be attached to a drill ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend that no.  As mentioned in the other post, the layer that gives the doors their wood grain appearance is likely very thin (unless they are solid wood doors, which I doubt).

So the main drawbacks of this method are:

- The disc sander will leave a spiral pattern in whatever you sand with it.  **I would never recommend this for wood** (metal yes)
- Unless you are very very careful, you will likely gouge the wood to the point the top layer is no longer nice at all.

What do you intend to do after you remove the finish?  Stain/Seal, Paint?

***Edit:*** You can attempt to utilize a gel stripper to remove the finish.  Now this would have to be done very carefully.

One or two layers should eat through the finish pretty quickly.  Do NOT let it sit for very long on veneer as it can penetrate and eat through the glue meaning...no more veneer.  (**I would like to put this disclaimer up front:  If not done carefully and correctly (and potentially even then) this can cause veneer to peel off.**

If you go this route don't leave the stripper on long...30 seconds to a minute tops, then scrape it off and wipe off any remainder.  If you can get through the finish, you can use sanding sponges and get the stain layer off by hand easily enough,

Comment: I would like the wood to keep the fresh and raw look, maybe a little darker that unfinished wood. Probably a sealing will have that effect. I might consider staining if I am not happy with the final look and I want to hide imperfections.
Since there since to be no tool to get me where I want I afraid that I might need to order new doors

Comment: It is generally (though not universally) tough to refinish a veneer.  The thinner the layer the harder it becomes.  This is mainly due to the fact that the veneer absorbs the stain and sealer meaning to refinish you have to sand away the wood that they penetrated...with a veneer that can be a challenge.  I did add a suggestion for pulling this off, see edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot James. At this point I am quite convinced that it is not worth the work to do all these and I am not very skilled either. 
I guess it will be easier to order custom ones. My other problem is the hardwood floor, I have to replace it and I am afraid that the contract that I want to hire wants to put subfloor which might rise the floor and male my opening s shorter which means that I will have to wait for the hardfloor to be installed.

Comment: You may be able to get your hands on something close enough and cut them to size.  An option at least.